# Is it possible to install vmware on system not inside OS?

Tags: operating-systems

I am searching if it is possible to load vmware on system startup and choose which os to launch. like Windows, linux, debian etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VMware is a company that makes many different virtualisation products, but I assume that you mean VMware Workstation, Fusion or Player.

You cannot do it with those virtual machine managers, which need to run on top of a host OS, but you can when using one of their hypervisors, ESX and ESXi.  ESXi is free.

When you boot the machine, the VMs will automatically start in their last known state, unless you configure them to do otherwise.

ESXi runs straight on top of the hardware, but you need to use hardware on the [HCL](http://www.vm-help.com/esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php).  There are some very cheap HP Proliant servers that you can buy that have the software embedded on SD cards on the motherboard, or have special motherboard USB sockets for this.

There is also the forthcoming MokaFive, which is a Type 1 hypervisor for desktops.  I think that this is the software you are waiting for.