# Host Independent Virtualization Solution

Tags: virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install vmware on system not inside OS?](https://superuser.com/questions/216623/is-it-possible-to-install-vmware-on-system-not-inside-os)

I would like to run few Virtual system on my system. I am running MAC, Ubuntu and few other OS using VMware, but I can only load those Virtual Systems, only after I run Vmware in Windows 7, which uses a huge chunk of my hardware. So I am searching for a solution, where I can run Virtual System without running a third party OS.

What are the available solutions for my cause?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the hardware for it (a CPU with Intel VT-x or AMD-V) and you don't mind changing your host, you could run KVM with hardware virtualization. The Linux kernel itself acts as the hypervisor, allowing it to run lighter than most other virtualization solutions.

Comment: I have Intel core I7 720Qm, which does support VT-x. BTW, what is hardware virtualization and KVM

Comment: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-assisted_virtualization

Comment: Also, What is hypervisor?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor

Comment: SO Kvm is like a OS, I install KVM first and then install windows 7, max, linux later then right

Comment: but it says `KVM (for Kernel-based Virtual Machine) is a full virtualization solution for Linux on x86 hardware containing virtualization extensions (Intel VT or AMD-V)` but I have x64 bit processor

Comment: @Starx x64 processors have x86 architecture + wider (64-bit ) registers. Your processor is capable of hardware virtualization

Comment: Core i7 is x86-64, not x64.

Comment: You install Linux, and in the process KVM gets installed along with it. You install Windows later within KVM.

Comment: So, it is not completely host independent as linux will be running on the background when using other OS right? Isn't it possible to run Virtual System except on an actual OS?

Comment: Strictly speaking Xen can, but even Xen needs an appropriate Dom0 to negotiate with the hardware and there is a very short list of OSes suitable for a Dom0.